# Moving DML Operation Outside a for loop

Tags: apex, trigger, dml

I have the following code and would like to perform the DML operation outside the loop. However, I cannot seem to find any way in doing this at the moment:

```
private void processResult(List<RS_Assessment__c> newlist){
    List<Id> activityList = new List<Id>();
    for (RS_Assessment__c assessment : newlist){
        if (assessment.Activity__c != null && assessment.Activity__r.Actual_Date__c == null){
            if (assessment.Activity__r.Last_Assessment_Date__c == null){
                activityList.add(assessment.Activity__c);
            }
        }
    }
    List<RS_Activity__c> processesToUpdate = [SELECT Id FROM RS_Activity__c WHERE Id IN: activityList];
    if (processesToUpdate.size() > 0){
        for (RS_Activity__c act : processesToUpdate){
            RS_Assessment__c assessment = [SELECT Id, Assessment_Date__c FROM RS_Assessment__c WHERE Activity__c  =: act.Id LIMIT 1]; //need to move soql out
            act.Actual_Date__c = assessment.Assessment_Date__c;
        }
        update processesToUpdate;
    }
}
```

I need to move the dml in the second for loop outside the loop. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a map and build it from the results of your `Activity` query.

The second part of your code should be rewritten as this:

```
RS_Activity__c[] updateProcesses = new RS_Activity__c[]{};
RS_Activity__c[] allProcesses = [SELECT Id FROM RS_Activity__c WHERE Id IN: activityList];
RS_Assessment__c[] assessments = [SELECT Id, Assessment_Date__c FROM RS_Assessment__c WHERE Activity__c  IN :activityList];

Map<Id,RS_Assessment__c> assessmentsByActivityId = new Map<Id,RS_Assessment__c>();

for (RS_Assessment__c assessment : asessments){
    assessmentsByActivityId.put(asessment.Activity__c,assessment);
}

for (RS_Activity__c act : allProcesses){
    RS_Assessment__c assessment = assessmentsByActivityId.get(act.Id);
    if (assessment == null){
        continue;
    }
    act.Actual_Date__c = assessment.Assessment_Date__c;
    updateProcesses.add(act);
}
update updateProcesses;
```

So, as you can see:

- Query into a list. Get all `RS_Assessment__c` objects.
- Build the map, indexed by `RS_Activity__c` id.
- Loop through RS_Activity__c records, and attempt to retrieve a related `RS_Assessment__c`.
- If found, perform change.

**UPDATE**
Have added an 'all' list and an 'update' list. Also, you don't need to check if the list is empty to call update. It will only error if it is null.

Comment: Beat me to the punch! +1 for also moving out SOQL.

Comment: Haha, I knew this one was going to need some quick action... :)

Comment: @CaspNZ thx for the help. but the processesToUpdate is actually meant to hold all the activities so is that redundant in this case?

Comment: What you can do is create a second activity list and put the items you want to update into that. That will minimise your amount of records updated. I didn't do that for this example because you had already called the first list list `processesToUpdate`. If you do want to do this, put the `Activity` to be updated into your second update list as soon as you have changed the `Actual_Date__c` value. Then call update after your `if` statement. Oh and you can remove the `processesToUpdate.size()` check.

Comment: Oh hang on I can see what needs to happen - stand by...

Comment: ok have updated - there is an 'all' list and an 'update' list. However, both techniques will work - just the update version will have a lesser impact on the db. Also, you don't need to check if the list is empty to call update. It will only error if it is null.